# Visualforce is very slow in Salesforce 1 App, how to improve speed

Tags: salesforce1-app

I created following vf page and added this as a tab in salesforce 1 mobile app, it takes around 20 to 25 seconds to load and show simple text 'Test page'. Any suggestions how to make this faster. Do I need to create lightning component and add to salesforce1 ?

```
  <apex:page sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false">
        Test Page ...
    </apex:page>
```

Why I am doing this => I created another page with custom code and JS and it was also loading really slow(around 20 sec), so I decided to test how much time it takes to load blank page, its nearly same load time.
Both pages do not have controller.

Note : I am connected to WiFi.

Comment: If you're doing this in sandbox check your instance. SFDC has been having some performance issues today - trust.salesforce.com.

Comment: Cs9 has been horribly slow for months now. If that's your instance, it would explain a lot.

Comment: I am on CS18 sandbox instance

Comment: This is pretty funny.. I don't think SFDC can dish this one off to your network bandwidth at your location. :)

Comment: @PrafullaPatil - did you find any root cause for this or any suggestions to improve this? I'm also having very slow loading issue to VF pages overridden for Edit/New actions even with stylesheets etc turned off.

Comment: We did not, planning to explore if Lightening component faster compared to Visualforce. Another option to consider is building standalone app with Ionic, we did POC and its super fast! - http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/10/ionic-tutorial-and-sample-application/